# Helping XeLaTeX Find TrueType Ligatures

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, ligatures

I’m using a `.ttf` version of the font Century Schoolbook in a `XeLaTeX` document, and I’m having some issues with ligatures and kerning. Here’s what the following code, compiled with `XeLaTeX` in `TeXShop`, outputs for me:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Century Schoolbook}

\begin{document}
fi fl f'
\end{document}
```

[image]

I’ve had the same issue using e.g. `Ligatures=Common` and other basic variants.

When I examined actual font files in FontBook, the ligatures were indeed there: glyphs 192 and 193 were the ligatures for fi and fl, respectively. Is this an issue of `XeLaTeX` simply failing to find them, then? And if so, is there a way I could point it in the right place?

As for the nasty looking f’ combination in the picture above, I suppose that’s not a ligature problem but a kerning one. I find it strange, but can easily fix it with a `\hspace` command, at least.

Comment: It’s hard to say what causes the problem unless we know the exact version of the font. Have you tried TeX Gyre Schola, which is based on the URW++ Century Schoolbook L?

Comment: I’m using Monotype’s Century Schoolbook, Version 2.35. I have tried TeX Gyre Schola, and it’s a fine typeface, but quite different from Monotype’s, which I would still like to get working.

Comment: Are you sure `Ligatures=TeX` is the right option to use? If you see Table 2 in the Fontspec docs, it specifies different options to use based on which OpenType table the ligatures are in (`rlig`, `liga`, `clig`, etc). You can probably examine the font, see under which tag your preferred ligatures occur, and then use the corresponding option.

Comment: Coincidentally I had a similar Century Schoolbook on my system, and I can see it's not an OpenType font at all — it's in an older format. None of the ligature tables exist. I can access the glyphs with `\symbol{"F001}`, `\symbol{"F002}`, `\symbol{"FB01}` and `\symbol{"FB02}` but I don't know how to make TeX pick up these glyphs in place of every `fi` and so on.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR My Century Schoolbook is TrueType, so really there was no point in me adding `Ligatures=TeX.` Force of habit. I’ve found that I can manually insert the glyphs by a similar method, so I suppose I’ll just do that. I also am having a similar issue with some OpenType fonts, however—if I load a font by file name I don’t get any ligatures, but if I load it by font name then I do. Strange.